# PHP “Call to a member function execute() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I currently have a very strange problem. I have this code on my website:

```
// Load the menu links from the database
$result = $dbc->prepare('SELECT id, linktext, visible, sort FROM content ORDER BY sort');
var_dump($result);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($id, $menu_linktext, $menu_visible, $menu_sort);
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
// If the link is visible create the link
if ($menu_visible == '1') {
    $menu_linktext_ = str_replace(' ','_',$menu_linktext);
    echo "<li><a href='?page=$menu_linktext_'>$menu_linktext</a></li>";
}
}
```

The var_dump returns bool(false). Which means there is no connection to the DB somehow but on the same page I have the exact same code and it works with out a problem.

Comment: What does `echo $dbc->error()` say?

Comment: It means that your query has failed - try echoing it out and running it directly in the database, and you should see what the error is.

Comment: Its possible that a vital piece of code/file is declared/included AFTER the problem code, but BEFORE the working code.  Without a broader code sample, it's difficult to say from the readers point-of-view.

Comment: Found the problem the id column didn't exist. I thought I had a id column for the page id's but the column was called pages. Feel rather silly now.